# MySQL COUNT() and FIND_IN_SET()

Tags: mysql, count

Is it possible to perform count with data stored as coma separated values?

For example I have two tables:

```
Items:
=====================
id  name  cats
=====================
1   John  1,2
2   Peter 3
3   Jack  2


Categories:
===========================
id    name    
=========================== 
1     Animals
2     Vegetables
3     Fruits
```

I want to select all categories and perform count on "cats" field.

The result should look something like:

```
Name          Counter
======================
Animals      1
Vegetables   2
Fruits       1
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  c.name,
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(i.id) 
  FROM
    Items AS i 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.id, i.cats)) AS total 
FROM
  categories AS c;
```

Comment: Normalising the data schema by adding a item_category table is what I'd recommend. Then it becomes simple. Violating 3rd normal form is normally a bad idea.

Comment: you can lean from here http://www.programering.com/a/MzMyUzNwATg.html

Comment: Have you tried your query? Do you get an error? It should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Time to time, we can't normalize data and it's fast to just find an SQL expression to manage this situation:

```
select count(*), c.name from items as i,category as c where find_in_set( c.id , i.cats ) !=0 group by c.name;


+----------+------------+
| count(*) | name       |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Animals    |
|        1 | Fruits     |
|        2 | Vegetables |
+----------+------------+
```